# What is the order of an unramified character?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, definition, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a local field and $G_K$ be its absolute Galois group. A **character** is a group homomorphism $\phi: G_K \to \mathbb{C}^*$ with finite image, i.e. $|\phi(G_K)| < \infty$. It is **unramified** if $\phi(I_K) = 1$ where $I_K$ denotes the inertia subgroup of $G_K$.

In the proof of Lemma 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4889.pdf), I found the following sentence:

> We have two cases: If F/K is not totally ramified, pick an
>   *unramified character $\phi$ of $G_K$ of order $n$* with $\phi(\operatorname{Frob}_K) = \chi(\operatorname{Frob}_K)^{-1}$.
>   Otherwise, pick any *unramified character $\phi$ of $G_K$ of order $n$*.

**Question**: What is the definition of the order of an unramified character?

I thought first it could have something to do with a power of $\phi$ (like with the order of group elements), but this does not make sense since $\phi$ is not an endomorphism. Could you explain what this means? Thank you!

Comment: The characters on $G_K$ form a group, don't they? The operation is just pointwise multiplication.

Comment: If $F/K$ is not totally ramified, then $I_K\leq G_K$ is normal subgroup. Then $\phi(I_K)=1$ means that this descends to character of $G_K/I_K$. In particular, this gives a character of non-ramified subextension $K_u/K$'s character. In particular, you can pick a character corresponding to frobenius element of residue field. The order of this character can be identified as the order of the corresponding group element of non-ramified subextension. Note for non-ramified case, you have galois group identification with galois group residue field which is cyclic.

Comment: Here's a useful fact: any finite subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$ is cyclic (indeed this is true for any field). The order of a character is the size of the image of $\phi$. Alternatively, it is the smallest non-zero $n$ such that $\phi^n=0$, where we multiply characters pointwise.